# LinkageError jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, transactions, linkageerror

I have a problem with this linkage error, we have projects with the same code and works :

```
this.plateformTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
this.plateformTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED);
TransactionStatus status = plateformTransactionManager.getTransaction(def);
```

Stack trace at runtime :

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.getTransaction(Lorg/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition;)  Lorg/springframework/transaction/TransactionStatus;" the class loader    (instance of  org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, com/as24/referentiel/daos/ExternalUserDAO, and the class loader (instance of  rg/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class,  org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager, have different Class Objects for the type org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition used in the Signature
```

I read it's a maven dependancies error but we used Spring only on version 3.0.7.REALEASE

I don't find any soutions on the web ...

Comment: Can you show how you obtained the `dataSource`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of shared libraries between between server and web application.

In java a class is identified by its **name** (including package name) and its **class loader** (which loaded it). So if you have the same `MyBean.class` inside web application `WEB-INF/classes` and also inside `${catalina.home}/lib`, these will be viewed as two different classes (i.e. `myBean instanceof MyBean == false`). When JVM approaches situation where some class is using class **XYZ** in its method signatures and **XYZ** is loaded by a different classloader than a class **XYZ** known by the current class loader, then `LinkageError` is raised.

---

You problem is that you have Spring dependencies (at least *spring-tx*) on the shared / system class loader and also within web application dependencies.

To solve your issue you need to do one of the following:

- remove Spring dependencies from server class-loaders
- remove duplicate dependency from the web application (mark it as `provided` dependency in POM)
- add duplicate dependencies on `endorsed` class-loader (by that web application class-loader will ignore the web application dependency).

Comment: I check my WEB-INF/lib and catalina.home : the spring-jdbc is only on catalina.home, the dependance is provided on the subproject and not include in master project

Comment: @FrancoisT The exception is clear. There is no doubt you have problem with spring-tx being loaded by two different class loaders (or maybe TransactionDefinition was packaged in a different JAR in previous Spring versions). Check your server configuration.

Comment: the problem was the spring-tx and not the spring-jdbc as I thought

Comment: There is a simple rule - every dependency should be either on server class-loader path or in webapp class-loader path. Never on both class-loaders' paths (unless you are 100% sure that is what you want). So check also other dependencies... if there are any duplicities, that is just another hidden issue waiting to happen.